# Best hardware for a cluster of linux machines

Tags: desktop, server, cluster-computing

I have a third party software which needs a lot of RAM for its functionality. I also have a method to make the software run in a distributed manner so that I am able to run it in hosts with limited RAM and just add more machines when needed.

So if my current requirement is 1TB of RAM, then I could use 16machines with 64GB of RAM, or 8 machines with 128GB of RAM. Ofcourse I'll take into account the OS RAM usage and any other things.

I've been doing this using cloud instances but it is proving to be costly and would like to move it to onpremise. My requirements are just the machine should be able to run Linux (say Ubuntu 22), have 128GB of RAM and a small SSD (128 or 256G), a Ethernet port. That's it. I do not need any other peripherals or anything more. The processor also need not be anything powerful (i3 should be enough).

I am not going the route of getting a server setup with dual processor and 2TB RAM or more in a single machine because the cost of it is more and it is difficult to scale slowly.

Is it possible to do such a setup cheaply and possibly add those machines in a rack when needed and what type of hardware would I have to choose to do so.